I installed Win10 guest in VirtualBox on; guest can't detect a USB lab device despite installed extensionpacks.Need USB filter setup tips. Dmesg lines
# ------ linux host dmesg after attaching the usb device
[  722.201389] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  722.349773] usb 3-2: no configurations
[  722.349796] usb 3-2: can't read configurations, error -22
[  722.477317] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  722.625750] usb 3-2: no configurations
[  722.625772] usb 3-2: can't read configurations, error -22
[  722.625954] usb usb3-port2: attempt power cycle
[  723.037376] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  723.057948] usb 3-2: no configurations
[  723.057971] usb 3-2: can't read configurations, error -22
[  723.189377] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  723.210226] usb 3-2: no configurations
[  723.210248] usb 3-2: can't read configurations, error -22
[  723.210433] usb usb3-port2: unable to enumerate USB device


virtualbox version: 7.0.20
win10 home as guest
Debian 12 as host
usb device to read: biologic potentiostate

using proper software from the company
the software was installed in a win10 laptop and the usb communication was tested positively !
